# Двойная диспетчеризация + удаление объектов в обработчике

Tags: c++, алгоритм, разработка-игр, проектирование

Необходимо реализовать взаимодействие между игровыми сущностями. В качестве опорной точки выбрана двойная диспетчеризация. Каждый класс наследуемый от базового класса Cell делегирует обработку взаимодействия классу Room.

```
// file   : entity/Avatar.hpp

#ifndef ENTITY_AVATAR_HPP
#define ENTITY_AVATAR_HPP

#include "Cell.hpp"

class Avatar : public Cell {
public:
  Avatar(Room& room);

  void interact(Cell& cell) override;
  void interact(Avatar& avatar) override;
  void interact(Food& food) override;
};

#endif /* ENTITY_AVATAR_HPP */

// file   : entity/Avatar.cpp
void Avatar::interact(Cell& cell)
{
  cell.interact(*this);
}

void Avatar::interact(Avatar& avatar)
{
  room.interact(*this, avatar);
}

void Avatar::interact(Food& food)
{
  room.interact(*this, food);
}
```

Все идеально до тех пор пока взаимодействие не подразумевает уничтожения одного или обоих взаимодействующих объектов.
Подскажите как при необходимости грамотно организовать удаление одного или обоих объектов. В данном случае проблема возникает из-за того что сначала ищутся все предполагаемые для взаимодействия с simulatedCell объекты и сохраняются в контейнер, после чего на каждой итерации может быть уничтожен как инициатор (simulatedCell) так и любой из найденных для взаимодействия объектов.

```
void Room::interact()
{
  for (Cell* simulatedCell: m_simulatedCells) {
    const auto& cells = m_gridmap.query(*simulatedCell);
    for (Cell* cell : cells) {
      cell->interact(*simulatedCell);
    }
  }
}

void Room::interact(Avatar& avatar1, Avatar& avatar2)
{
  // вот здесь нельзя просто взять и удалить уничтоженный объект
}
```

Comment: Может быть для объекта ввести некий флаг `zombie`, говорящий о том, что объект уже не жив. Реальное уничтожение производить в безопасном для этого месте. Если я правильно понял проблему.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь закодировать игровую логику отношением между классами. Это скорее всего не сработает. Вот [серия статей Эрика Липперта](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) по этому поводу (там про C#, но смысл ровно тот же).

Comment: @VladD, хорошая серия. Все еще не прочитал, но у меня в некотором роде более простая задача - есть только один уровень наследования, почти все типы взаимодействуют друг с другом, между двумя объектами (разного или того же типа) возможен только один вид взаимодействия. Как по мне класический пример для двойной диспетчеризации.

Comment: @alexolut, я именно так и делаю. Хотелось ознакомиться с разными вариантами и избежать оверхеда при поиске кандидатов на удаление в безопасном месте. В данный момент просто завел еще один контейнер куда помещаются указатели на zombie-объекты. Получается вместо просмотра на каждой итерации всех объектов, которых несколько тысяч, просматривается обычно пустой контейнер.

Comment: @sba: Идея этой серии в том, что для описания правил лучше не пытаться <s>натянуть сову на глобус</s> выразить это в терминах наследования, а просто завести отдельную сущность «свод правил», которой и делегировать все решения по логике игры.

Comment: @VladD, возможно я что-то недопонимаю, но где именно в моей модели правила взаимодействия организованы через наследование? Есть следующие классы: Avatar, Food, Mass, Virus, Phage, Mother. Почти все взаимодействуют друг с другом, и возможно между собой. Без общего предка Cell все взаимодействие можно реализовать одним длинным куском кода, попарно перебирая елементы из 6 контейнеров. Двойная диспетчеризация предоставляет в удобном виде табличку с заполненными вариантами взаимодействия, не более. Виртуальный вызов собственно и делегирует обработку в Room, разруливая кто с кем взаимодействует.

Comment: @sba: Ну, Эрик столкнулся с проблемой даже на двух классах...